# Extending ArrayList with an abstract class in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, abstract-class

This is a problem I've been working on for a little while now and I've barely made any progress. I've been running into a lot of problems trying to use an abstract class when extending ArrayList.

My first step was to define three classes, Circle, Rectangle, and Triangle that are all concrete subclasses of an abstract class GeometricObject. The base class has abstract methods `getArea()` and `getPerimeter()` that are overridden in the subclasses by the specific `getPerimeter()` and `getArea()` formula for that particular object. This part is completed and is working as intended.

The next part is where I'm having trouble. I'm supposed to define a new class `GeoemetricObjectList` that extends `ArrayList<GeometricObject>`. This class should override the `add()`, `remove()`, and `clear()` methods. This class keeps a totalArea and totalPerimeter variable of the objects on the list.

Right now I've created a, quite frankly, messy if statement list in my `GeometricObjectList add()` method that I'd like to clean up. Here is my code for that class so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

@SuppressWarnings("hiding")
public class GeometricObjectList<GeometricObject> extends ArrayList<GeometricObject>{

    final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public double totalArea = 0;
    public double totalPerimeter = 0;


    public boolean add(GeometricObject element){
        if(element instanceof Rectangle) {
            totalArea += ((Rectangle)element).getArea();
            totalPerimeter += ((Rectangle)element).getPerimeter();
        }
        if(element instanceof Circle) {
            totalArea += ((Circle)element).getArea();
            totalPerimeter += ((Circle)element).getArea();
        }
        if(element instanceof Triangle) {
            totalArea += ((Triangle)element).getArea();
            totalPerimeter +=((Triangle)element).getArea();
        }

        return super.add(element);
    }

    public boolean remove(GoemetricObject element) {

        return super.remove(element);
    }

    public void clear() {

    }

}
```

When I simply write `totalArea += element.getArea()` I get the error "The method `getArea()` is undefined for the type GeometricObject but in my GeometricObject class I have a public abstract `getArea()` that is overridden by the `getArea()` method in each concrete (Triangle, Circle, Rectangle) class.

My next issue is with the `remove()` method in GeometricObjectList. It looks like this:

```
public boolean remove(GeometricObject element) {

    return super.remove(element);
}
```

I am getting the error "Name clash: The method remove(GeometricObject) of type `GeometricObjectList<GeometricObject>` has the same erasure as remove(Object) of type ArrayList but does not override it". I never received this error when creating the `add()` method.

Any help with this is REALLY greatly appreciated. If there's any more info you need ask for it and I'll have it up in a second!

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("hiding")?

Comment: You forgot the @Override annotation.

Comment: Part of the problem is that `public class GeometricObjectList<GeometricObject>` is declaring a *type parameter* named GeometricObject. I assume you meant `public class GeometricObjectList extends ArrayList<GeometricObject>`.

Comment: This looks like a bad design. Extending ArrayList is (almost) **never** the answer. In this case I would rather have a utility method that can do calculateArea(List<GeometricObject> objects);

Comment: @MohdAdnan The question is about an error, so it's fine here.

Comment: @nablex Unfortunately this is how I'm being asked to do it. I would never do it this way if it were up to me.

Answer (score 2):

You really had several  different issues - including spelling and hiding,

```
// Make sure you have these methods in your GeometricObject.
// private static abstract class GeometricObject {
//  public abstract double getArea();
//  public abstract double getPerimiter();
// }

// Do not use that annotation. It was warning you!
public class GeometricObjectList extends
    ArrayList<GeometricObject> {

  final static long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public double totalArea = 0;
  public double totalPerimeter = 0;

  public boolean add(GeometricObject element) {
    if (element != null && super.add(element)) {
      totalArea += element.getArea(); // add area
      totalPerimeter += element.getPerimiter(); // add perimeter
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public boolean remove(GeometricObject element) { // Spelling!
    if (element != null && super.remove(element)) {
      totalArea -= element.getArea(); // subtract area
      totalPerimeter -= element.getPerimiter(); // subtract perimeter
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public void clear() {
    super.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind the OP is trying to add custom functionality to this list: "This class keeps a totalArea and totalPerimeter variable of the objects on the list".

Comment: +1 I think the main problem was that the type parameter was the same name as the `GeometricObject` class type.

Comment: This helped a ton! I figured there was something fishy going on with the type parameter. This stuff is still new to me so I got a bit confused with what the seperate sets of "<>" did.

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's start with first things first.

This class declaration isn't doing what you believe it's doing:

```
public class GeometricObjectList<GeometricObject> extends ArrayList<GeometricObject>
```

Java is treating `GeometricObject` as a **type parameter**.  If you want to bound the generic strictly to only instances of a `GeometricObject`, change that signature to this:

```
public class GeometricObjectList<T extends GeometricObject> extends ArrayList<T>
```

Then Java will identify the type parameter `T` to only be instances of `GeometricObject` and its children.

You could also eschew the need for the generic type argument altogether and have your `ArrayList` tightly bound to `GeometricObject` without a generic:

```
public class GeometricObjectList extends ArrayList<GeometricObject>
```

Next, the signature of `add` gets to change.  Since `T` is already bound to be an instance of `GeometricObject`, we don't need to explicitly say that's what we're adding.

```
public boolean add(T element)
```

If you elected not to use `T`, then you would keep your signature the same.

In either case, the casts also become redundant and can go away.

Finally, your `remove` method isn't overriding the inherited `remove` - it needs to match the signature as well.

```
public boolean remove(Object element)
```